# I have same Entity in 2 different hazelcast member (ex: "mapOfA, mapOfB"). I want to update this object from one member synchronously. Is it possible?

Tags: java, hazelcast

@Configuration
public class HazelcastConfiguration {

```
@Bean
public Config config() {
    return new Config();
}

@Bean
public HazelcastInstance instance(Config config) {
    return Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
}

@Bean
public IMap<Long, Firm> mapOfFirm(HazelcastInstance instance) {
    return instance.getMap("mapOfFirm");
}
```

}

//how to configure this class or what to do something else ?

Answer (score 0):

You can either use transactions to update multiple data structures in one go, or make those map[PartitionAware](https://docs.hazelcast.org//docs/3.12.1/manual/html-single/index.html#partitionaware) and update both entities with an EntryProcessor in a single operation. I suggest the PartitionAware approach.

Comment: after updating/deleting entity i want THIS ENTITY must be updated in all cluster(member - sorry don't remember exactly). At present if i update entity in "mapOfA" the same entity in "mapOfB" do not have notice of from this changes. How can i do sync of this ?

Comment: Updating one entry in a map is reflected in all cluster members, so no worries about that. Updating an entry in map B together with an entry in map A can be achieved with co-locating them in the same member (using PartitionAware) and processing both of them in the same EntryProcessor in one go. Please check the "Order" and "Customer" example in the docs link I've shared.

Comment: Thank you very much for answer. I haven't test yet after testing return back result....